# CodeEval Submission, program works on my computer but not when I submit it. C

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

I am doing the fizz buzz challenge in C on CodeEval. It works fine on my computer but when I go to submit on CodeEval I get a failure and a 0 score. It says I have a buffer overflow error but it runs fine on my computer and is producing the exact output that the challenge is requesting.

```
/*Program Written and Designed by Ryan Sharpe*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* printNumbers(int A, int B, int max)
{
  char* num = (char*)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
  int i = 1;
  while(i < max+1)
  {
    if(i % A == 0 && i % B > 0)
      strcpy(num,"F");
    else if(i % B == 0 && i % A > 0)
      strcpy(num,"B");
    else if(i % A == 0 && i % B == 0)
      strcpy(num,"FB");
    else
      strcpy(num,"X");

    if(strncmp(num,"X", 2) == 0)
      printf("%d%s", i, " ");
    else
      printf("%s%s", num, " "); 
    i++;   
  }
  printf("\n");
  free(num);
  return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE* f;
  f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int A, B, max;
  while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d", &A, &B, &max) != EOF)
    printNumbers(A, B, max);
  fclose(f); 
  return 0;
}
```

The error that CodeEval is giving is this: Which is something that I did not get running my program:

```
* buffer overflow detected *: /binary terminated ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ff699aad807] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109700)[0x7ff699aac700] /binary[0x4007a0] /binary[0x400857] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ff6999c476d] /binary[0x400639] ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1334 /binary 00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 1334 /binary 00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 1334
/binary 018c3000-018e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
[heap] 7ff69978d000-7ff6997a2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 134950
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7ff6997a2000-7ff6999a1000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 134950
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7ff6999a1000-7ff6999a2000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 134950
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7ff6999a2000-7ff6999a3000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 134950
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 7ff6999a3000-7ff699b58000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 134939
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 7ff699b58000-7ff699d57000 ---p 001b5000 ca:01 134939
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 7ff699d57000-7ff699d5b000 r--p 001b4000 ca:01 134939
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 7ff699d5b000-7ff699d5d000 rw-p 001b8000 ca:01 134939
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so 7ff699d5d000-7ff699d62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 7ff699d62000-7ff699d84000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 134929 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so 7ff699f6c000-7ff699f6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 7ff699f7f000-7ff699f84000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 7ff699f84000-7ff699f85000 r--p 00022000 ca:01 134929
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so 7ff699f85000-7ff699f87000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 134929
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so 7fff5e021000-7fff5e042000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack] 7fff5e1ff000-7fff5e200000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
[vdso] ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
[vsyscall]
```

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean there's not a problem with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy(num,"FB");
```

This is the problem. Earlier, you allocate space for only two characaters in `num`, but this call will write 3 characters to `num`: `F`, `B`, and a null-terminator. This creates undefined behavior.

The fact that it works on your computer simply means you got lucky.

Comment: Thank you very much. I put 3 in my calloc param and that seemed to work. I think I will start adding memwatch to my programs to keep track of memory better.

Comment: @user3312266: That seems like an extremely misguided "solution". What you *should* be doing is think and understand what's going on.

Comment: From what I understand, I allocated space for 2 characters when I should have been allocating space for 3. Not allocating space for 3 is what was causing memory issues. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @DrewMcGowen said...

This line

```
while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d", &A, &B, &max) != EOF)
```

should be

```
while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d", &A, &B, &max) == 3)
```

Also, instead of using:

```
char* num = (char*)calloc(3, sizeof(char));
```

you can just use:

```
char num[3];
```

Using `malloc/calloc` is useful only when you don't know the size of an array. It's better to use an array if you know the size.

If you decide to use:

```
char num[3];
```

make sure to remove the line

```
free(num);
```

Comment: Also, the return type of `printNumbers` should just be `void`, not `void *`